# Pokemon go what terrain do Dratini spawn?

Tags: pokemon-go

I jumped on pokemon go 'gold fever' yesterday. So far I have noticed that fish-likes are spawning near the sea very well.

**What sort of terrain would one look for Dratini?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dratini are also water-dwelling. They're a little on the rare side.

Several weeks ago, Dratini were commonly documented in "nests," where clusters of them would be found with good frequency, but such nests have all since been rotated to hold different Pokémon. That said, there are still sparing sightings of Dratini clusters. You may be able to ask around and see if anyone else playing the game in your area has seen them.

Comment: Hi Eikre, thanks. Do you think sea will do or I need lakes and ponds? I will test sea by driving near the shore in UK Kent and will report. Thanks again.

Comment: Here in Northern Virginia, I've seen the most Dratini by the shore of Oldtown, Alexandria. So it does seem that the oceans are fine. It's my suspicion that, as a rule, the *character* of a body of water isn't a relevant concern.

Comment: The main thing to keep in mind is if a body of water in real life isn't showing as water on the map (as in, a small lake or river is missing), then it's unlikely to count as "water". Otherwise, if it's blue, it's water. You might still find larger amounts of water - like sea - are better spawn locations for certain Pokemon though.

Comment: Theory is plausible. Did two runs in a car yesterday by the sea driving around 10-25mph https://www.google.co.uk/maps/dir/51.0778902,1.1792601/51.0521992,1.0380633/@51.0548091,1.0358961,16z/data=!4m24!4m23!1m20!3m4!1m2!1d1.1647394!2d51.0748409!3s0x47debf26c83c90b7:0xdd1a79785a5e90f8!3m4!1m2!1d1.1504521!2d51.0738993!3s0x47debf3eb9d1dcd9:0xa15d03f525958cfe!3m4!1m2!1d1.1148197!2d51.0705043!3s0x47dec0a29961be25:0x1e18cb336b852e6b!3m4!1m2!1d1.0784657!2d51.0684034!3s0x47dec0e0e9ef9c9b:0x696315427d2765bf!1m0!3e0 got one near Seapoint Canoe Centre Folkestone CT21 5ZY. Will do more testing today.